# how can I bind an event to the clear x button icon in internet explorer (see pic)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, button, bind

I've found that the little x icon in IE 9 and lower does not bind to any of my jquery events like it does in IE 10 (and better browsers like chrome). This is the x icon I'm talking about:

[image]

Is there a way I can manually bind this little x icon? I've seen lots of posts on how to hide the x button using css like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  ::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

but I actually wont to bind a click event to this thing. can it be done?

Comment: Could you please try to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in order to see it in action ? Seems strange.

Comment: here's kinda what I'm trying to do. However, instead of a change event, I want to be able to actually catch the click of the x button: http://jsfiddle.net/MDMV5/

Comment: I understood what you were trying to do, but we need to see espacialy this "x" button that causes the issue.

Comment: The "little x icon" isn't put there by IE9 itself (this feature was added to IE10). Are you trying to use IE10's F12 Developer tools to emulate IE9 or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to bind to pseudo elements. You can however create a div and position it absolutely over top of it and then bind to that. That should stop the user from clicking the actual x.

Comment: I just created an icon to cover that silly pseudo element and it works great. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any HTML element will have a click event. I do not completely get the context of this "x" button that you mention; however, if this element was manipulated in the DOM such that it was re-rendered (e.g. $("#somediv").dialog()), then any javascript functionality or manipulation attached to it prior to that call will be erased. The best solution in this case is to define the event nature after all manipulations are complete.

If an element is manipulated on the fly, that element's events may need rebinding afterwards.

In addition, if this is a jQuery DOM created object, you may have to drill down by $(query).find(query) (or up depending on the reference by $(query).parent()).